# mysql sql avg function does not return correct values?

Tags: mysql, sql

[I've my table with structure like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oluPn.jpg)

Now I want to produce a table that show final average of each student by formula:

```
Final_avg=0.15x(average of exam= test1,test2 and test3) 
         +0.25x(exam=midterm)+0.6x(exam=terminal);
```

I've tried this query but I'm getting incorrect values of fainal_avg

```
select e.sname AS sn 
     , AVG( CASE WHEN e.exam IN ('test1','test2','test4') THEN e.average END )  AS t_avg
     , e3.average as mid
     , e2.average as main
     , 0.15*e.average+0.25*e3.average+0.6*e2.average AS f_avg 
  from $form as e 
  JOIN $form as e2 
    ON e2.sname = e.sname AND e2.exam = 'terminal'
  JOIN $form as e3 
    ON e3.sname = e.sname AND e3.exam = 'midterm'
 group by e.sname 
 order by f_avg  desc
```

The final average that I get from the query is inncorect with one that I get by calculating using calculator

[This is table for correct and incorrect final average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTBFo.jpg)

Comment: First read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question.

Comment: Format your code please

Comment: And then see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: We're going to need a table structure and sample data to help you out here.

Comment: Are you trying to do average of averages? Mathematically that doesn't make sense to me. It will never give you the right answer

Comment: This SQL query is problematic for several reasons. Please provide sample data for the `$form` table, and the expected result for that data.

Comment: consider creating an SQLFiddle

Comment: for f_avg please apply MDAS syntax

Comment: You forgot to tell us *what* you are trying to calculate. Why do you consider some results wrong? Please show some rows with sample data (just for one sname, term and year) and show us the value you get and the one you want to get instead.

Comment: Please don't post images. These are blocked for many of us. Paste the text instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping by `e.sname`, but access `e.average` in your select clause. As there are several records per sname, it is left to chance which value the DBMS picks from them. You want an aggregation such as `AVG(e.sname)` instead, in your case: `AVG(CASE WHEN e.exam IN ('test1','test2','test4') THEN e.average END)`.

This mix of self joins and conditional aggregation is kind of clumsy, however. I suggest either to aggregate your test records before joining or not joining at all instead.

**Aggregate test records before joining**

```
select
  sname, 0.15 * tst.average + 0.25 * mid.average + 0.6 * trm.average as result
from
(
  select sname, avg(average) as average
  from $form
  where exam in ('test1','test2','test4')
  group by sname
) tst
join $form trm on trm.sname = tst.sname and exam = 'terminal'
join $form mid on mid.sname = tst.sname and exam = 'midterm';
```

**Mere aggregation, no join**

```
select
  sname, 
  0.15 * avg(case when exam in ('test1','test2','test4') then average end) + 
  0.25 * avg(case when exam = 'midterm' then average end) + 
  0.6 * avg(case when exam = 'terminal' then average end) as result
from $form
group by sname;
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns the average value of given argument, which is field name of a table.
The Distinct option may be used to calculate average of only distinct values from the given set of values.
If we want to find average marks from table student where marks are given in the column s_marks.
[For More Click](https://sbrau.blogspot.com/2019/10/mysql-avg-function_5.html?m=1)